# Error en definición de función en C

Tags: c, funciones

Tengo un problema con este código, cuando llamo la función `matrixsuma(A,B,C)` no obtengo la matriz deseada, sin embargo cuando corro solo la función `matrix` suma como main obtengo la matríz perfectamente.

Espero me puedan ayudar a ver mi error:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 20
int i,j,n,input;  /*Counters for the matrix elements, matrix size*/

float A[MAX][MAX], B[MAX][MAX], C[MAX][MAX];    /*Defining the matrix array*/

int main()

{

    float matrixsuma(float A[i][j], float B[i][j], float C[i][j]);
    matrixsuma(A, B, C);
}

float matrixsuma(float A[i][j], float B[i][j], float C[i][j])
{
    printf("You choose to sum the matrices\n");

    printf("Enter the matrix size\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Now you'll be asked to enter the matrices\n");
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
       for(j=1; j<=n; j++)
        {
            printf("Enter the element A[%d][%d]\n", i,j);
            scanf("%f", &A[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Cuando compilo y ejecuto me pide la matriz y por ejemplo en una matriz 2x2 al meter los elementos 1,2,3,4, el resultado es una matríz con elementos 3,4,3,4

Comment: me da la impresión de que falta código, a que te refieres con el resultado es 3,4,3,4 ? es el resultado de la suma (que no se ve en el código) o es el resultado de leer el `stdin` con `scanf` en la matriz A ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int main()
{
  float matrixsuma(float A[i][j], float B[i][j], float C[i][j]); // <<<---
  matrixsuma(A, B, C);
}
```

Las funciones anidadas no son algo permitido por el estándar de C. Si es cierto que algunas extensiones del compilador pueden activar esta característica pero no es lo más recomendable.

Por claridad de código las definiciones de funciones (por ejemplo no dar a entender que hay funciones anidadas) deberían estar fuera del main.

```
float matrixsuma(float A[i][j], float B[i][j], float C[i][j]);

int main()
{
  matrixsuma(A, B, C);
}
```

Por otro lado hay que ser muy cautos a la hora de hacer uso de variables globales. El problema que tienen las variables globales es que al ser accesibles desde toda la aplicación es dificil controlar el acceso a la variable, además de ser problemáticas en entornos multi-hilo.

Hablando sobre tu problema, la función está mal declarada:

```
float matrixsuma(float A[i][j], float B[i][j], float C[i][j])
{
}
```

`i` y `j` no son datos constantes sino variables. En el caso de arrays multidimensionales el compilador necesita conocer el tamaño de ciertas dimensiones para que los accesos a los elementos de dicho array sean satisfactorios.

En el caso de arrays bidimiensionales el compilador necesita conocer el tamaño de la segunda dimensión:

```
float matrixsuma(float A[][MAX], float B[][MAX], float C[][MAX])
{
}
```

Aunque si se desea se puede poner también el tamaño de la primera dimensión aunque, en este caso, dicho dato no tendrá consecuencias:

```
float matrixsuma(float A[MAX][MAX], float B[MAX][MAX], float C[MAX][MAX])
{
}
```

Y, bueno, a modo de consejo te diría que el código que rellena la matriz a partir de la entrada del usuario debería ir en una función independiente.

Un saludo.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, gracias.

He corregido la declaración de la variable 
matrixsuma(A[MAX][MAX],B[MAX][MAX],C[MAX][MAX])
y la declaré fuera del main(), ahora el programa hace lo que debe hacer. También voy a crear la función para rellenar la matríz. 

Saludos.